# Where I can download Flash Builder 4.0 Premium Trial version?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flexbuilder

I went to adobe site. It have Flash Builder 4.5/4.6 now. where I can download older
version(4.0)?

Comment: Why do you want the older version? The new one is better.

Comment: sure, but i am having automation licance issue in FB4.5, while it is working correctly in FB4.0.

Comment: See the comparison between 4.0 and 4.6 here: http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder/buying-guide.html

Comment: That's what you get when asking something to a developper. He'll explain you why you don't need it.

Comment: This is a little bit older post, but it's ranked high in google for people looking for the trial version (which can be registered with a valid serial). They are available here: http://trials2.adobe.com/AdobeProducts/FLBR/4/win32/FlashBuilder_4_LS10.exe

http://trials2.adobe.com/AdobeProducts/FLBR/4/osx10/FlashBuilder_4_LS10.dmg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found licenced version of older virsion(FB4.0) at amazon.
Concluding: We cannot get older version trial from adobe.

Answer (score 5):

The links at the bottom of this page are still good: http://www.mydigitallife.info/adobe-flash-builder-4-free-download-with-serial-number/

I had to remove other versions of Flash Builder using the Adobe Suite Cleaner Tool (downloadable here: http://www.adobe.com/support/contact/cscleanertool.html) for it to run.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you can't : http://forums.adobe.com/thread/850869

Here's all I could find : http://www.adobe.com/support/flex/downloads_updaters.html#flex4

Comment: This looks like bad strategy from adobe.

Answer (score 0):

After you install 4.0 from the links in the other posts you can get the patch update to 4.0.1 with this link:

http://www.adobe.com/support/flex/downloads_updaters.html#flex4